# Why are some of Kids' awards rewarded to non-kids' movies?

Tags: film-industry, awards

For example, one of Nickelodeon Kids' Choice Awards, entitled Kids' Choice Award for Favorite Male Buttkicker has been rewarded to Liam Hemsworth for his role in *The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 1*. Also, Hugh Jackman was nominated for his role in *X-Men: Days of Future Past* and some other non-appropriate films for kids.

But why should it be done in this way? X-Men movies, for example, are full of violence.

Is it really kids' choice?

Comment: You're a child until you're 18. Presumably that's the distinction they have to use; there's no other legal delineation.

Comment: Days of Future Past has worldwide certifications between Age 11 and Age 16 - mostly around 12-13.

Comment: for example *X-Men: Days of Future Past* has been rated PG-13; so the banned people from watching it are kids too. I also think the Kids title is controversial.

Comment: PG-13 doesn't mean children under 13 are banned from watching it, it just means they should be accompanied by adults, and even that's not mandatory. R-rated movies are the ones that children can't attend.

Comment: @F1Krazy Not quite true: “R – Restricted - Under 17 requires accompanying parent or adult guardian.” Only NC-17 is a complete prohibition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Nick.tv, although the winners are selected by their young viewers, the nominees are selected by Nickelodeon themselves, based on *whatever criteria they see fit*.

> Nickelodeon and Nickelodeon International will be responsible for
> managing the KCA and all matters related thereto including **the
> selection of nominees**, administration of voting, and presentation of
> the awards.
>
> [HOW VOTING WORKS FOR THE NICKELODEON KIDS' CHOICE AWARDS 2022](https://kca.nick.tv/legal/ecz2cb/how-voting-works)

There doesn't seem to be any consistent metric used, other than that the films are popular and successful and likely to appeal to their core audience (e.g. [kids aged 6-18](https://deadline.com/2020/05/nickelodeons-kids-choice-awards-reaches-2-4-million-viewers-in-live3-1202929300/) and their parents). The median rating for the winners of the ['butt-kickers' category (both male and female)](https://kidschoiceawards.fandom.com/wiki/The_Award,_itself) seems to be a PG-13.